Make writable nested serializers and PrimaryKeyRelatedField usable at the same time in Django REST framework
I would like to have the API of my model accept either the primary key of an existing object of the related model (PrimaryKeyRelatedField) or all the required fields to create a new object of the related model.
So that the user of the API can decide what option to use depending on whether there already is an object to use or a new one has to be created.
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'street', 'location', 'country']

Like this the serializer accepts the primary key of a location object as it becomes a PrimaryKeyRelatedField by default.
"location": 1


class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = LocationSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'street', 'location', 'country']

When I set the location field to be a LocationSerializer it accepts the information to create a new location but not a primary key anymore.
"location": {
    "name": "ABCDE",
    "zip": "12345"
}

I would like to have the API accept both so that the user of the API can decide whether he wants to reuse an existing location object or create a new one.
Is this possible?
